Spellstrike doesn't require an empty hand to use right?
So, I kind of wanted to clarify something, when it comes to spellstrike you don't need an empty hand to use spells through the weapon correct?
So, if I wanted to run a Myrmidarch magus, and fight with a hand crossbow in one hand and a sword in the other, I couldn't use standard spells, but I could still channel spells through the weapons despite my hands being full. Say frostbite through the sword and snowball from the hand crossbow? Could that work?
Quick Edit:I wanna make clear that this build would largely forgo the use of spell combat in favor or sticking to spell strike and ranged spellstrike. If that does not work either then I intend to make it so that either the crossbow or the weapon can be swapped out at a moments notice.

Note that whatever the correct answer to this question is you still explicitly need a free hand for Spell Combat (unless you take an archetype that changes that).

Spellstrike doesn’t require a free hand, but…
…you will probably need a free hand anyway.
Spellstrike does not require a free hand

Spellstrike (Su): At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack. Instead of the free melee touch attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, a magus can make one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell. If successful, this melee attack deals its normal damage as well as the effects of the spell. If the magus makes this attack in concert with spell combat, this melee attack takes all the penalties accrued by spell combat melee attacks. This attack uses the weapon's critical range (20, 19–20, or 18–20 and modified by the keen weapon property or similar effects), but the spell effect only deals ×2 damage on a successful critical hit, while the weapon damage uses its own critical modifier.

This is the full and complete text for the spellstrike ability. It does not mention a requirement of a free hand, so it doesn’t have one. And Paizo was aware of this: consider the eldrictch archer magus archetype, which gets modified versions of spell combat and spellstrike:

Ranged Spell Combat (Ex): Instead of a light or one-handed melee weapon, an eldritch archer must use a ranged weapon for spell combat. She doesn’t need a free hand for ranged spell combat. The eldritch archer cannot accept an attack penalty to gain a bonus on concentration checks to cast a spell defensively.
This ability modifies spell combat.
Ranged Spellstrike (Su): At 2nd level, whenever an eldritch archer casts a spell that calls for a ranged attack, she can deliver the spell through a ranged weapon she wields as part of a ranged attack. Instead of the free ranged attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, an eldritch archer can make one free ranged attack with a ranged weapon (at her highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell. The attack does not increase the spell’s range.
If the spell can normally affect multiple targets, only a single missile, ray, or effect accompanies each attack; if the spell allows multiple attacks and the eldritch archer can make additional ranged attacks as part of a full-round action with spell combat, one additional ray, missile, or effect from the spell accompanies each subsequent ranged attack the eldritch archer makes in the same round until all attacks allowed by the spell are made. Unused missiles, rays, or effects remaining at the end of the eldritch archer’s turn are wasted.
This ability alters spellstrike.

As Aunt Aunyme comments, the regular spell combat requires a free hand. The eldritch archer’s ranged spell combat, therefore, explicitly states that “[The eldritch archer] doesn’t need a free hand for ranged spell combat.” The same archetype’s ranged spellstrike ability, however, doesn’t mention free hands—because it doesn’t need to, the magus’s regular spellstrike doesn’t require one.
Spell combat does
Already mentioned, but spell combat requires a free hand. The myrmidarch archetype—unlike the eldritch archer—does not waive that requirement.
You really ought to use eldritch archer. It’s a far better archetype than myrmidarch. And your plan to ignore spell combat is not a good one: spell combat is what makes the magus good. Spellstrike is iconic, but it’s not actually all that good: the damage of a single weapon attack doesn’t really add that much to your turn most of the time. Casting a spell without that extra damage is nearly as good (or better, since it’s more accurate).
Spells usually do, too
Most spells have somatic components, and somatic components usually require a free hand. There are a number of workarounds here—you can trivially let go of a two-handed weapon, cast a spell, and then grab it again so you can attack two-handed, you can use a clawhand shield, you can use a wizard hook, and so on.1 Notably, however, none of these is a sword and hand crossbow combination; you’d have to go with a heavy shield bash and hand crossbow or hook and hand crossbow instead of the sword. The “revised v.3.5 edition” of Dungeons & Dragons—which Pathfinder 1e copied for its foundation—offered many more options, such as the Somatic Weaponry feat from Complete Mage, but for whatever reason, Paizo hasn’t written anything like that for Pathfinder—though Kobold Press has, as a 3rd-party feat.

None of these are compatible with regular spell combat, which explicitly requires a free hand separately from the requirement for somatic spells.


I appreciate your advice, but I believe I will stick with the myrmidarch, as I find the idea that something with access to both sprightly armor as well as the barroom brawler+Abundant tactics  combo could be considered bad. Besides any archtype that stacks with bladebound is worth a second look.

@Masakan Abundant Tactics and Barroom Brawler is a pretty pricey combination, as nice as the effect is. Sprightly Armor isn’t worth the price; Improved Initiative is as good or better until you get +5 armor (which should probably be never, special armor properties are worth more than enhancement bonuses). If you think myrmidarch is a good idea, you shouldn’t be a magus in the first place—it’s that bad. Just play a fighter or something. And any GM who blocks bladebound and eldritch archer is not one I’d play with; those are incompatible only by the flimsiest of technicalities.

Then you wouldn't want to play with me cause the fact remains they are not.

It is possible with the right conditions.
Though Spellstrike itself does not mention needing a hand free it incorporates the action of casting a spell where it states "whenever a Magus casts a spell".
Components are requirements of "Casting a Spell".
If the spell has Component "S" then you need a free hand. (Unless specifically stated otherwise by a rule override, specific trumps general.)
Somatic (S):
"A somatic component is a measured and precise movement of the hand. You must have at least one hand free to provide a somatic component."
Repeatedly drawing and stowing weapons
Switching between a hand-crossbow and a sword from one round to the next could work with Spellstrike combined with Quick Draw, Quick Stow, and either a standard and a quickened spell. This would use a free action for Quick Draw, a standard (or quick) action for casting a touch spell, and a move action for Quick Stow.
Melee round choices:

free action: quick draw sword (or have in hand already),
standard action: cast touch spell Frostbite using Spellstrike and get 1 free melee attack with sword,
move action: quick stow sword into sheath.

Ranged round choices:

free action: quick draw hand-crossbow,
move action: load hand-crossbow (provokes AoO),
quickened action: cast touch spell Snowball using Spellstrike and get 1 free melee attack with hand-crossbow,
standard action swapped for move action to Quick Stow hand-crossbow.

Any round in which you need to load the hand-crossbow and do a Quick Stow you will need two move actions, to do that you need to switch the standard action to a move action which means you no longer have a standard action to cast a spell (Somatic or otherwise). Provided you can afford the spell slot 4 levels higher than the spell being cast to make it quickened then you have a viable method of using either the sword or hand-crossbow with a Spellstrike attack in any round.
Holding weapons in-hand (but not using both in the same round)
Attempting to "hold" a hand-crossbow in one hand and "hold" a sword in the other and use Spellstrike will only work for one shot of the hand-crossbow (assuming it is preloaded) and as long as the spell has no "S" Component. The problem with reloading the hand-crossbow still arises, not the move action this time but that you need two hands to reload. Nothing helps with this need for two hands.
Searching the Spell DB shows there are only 4 spells which are touch and non-Somatic on the Magus spell list. Blur, Darkness, Displacement, and Light. I doubt I'd want my enemy to gain advantage from Blur or Displacement, Light is pretty useless against most things, and Darkness would only be useful if the Magus had Darkvision and the target didn't.
The original question makes no mention of Spell Combat, but as @Anne-Aunyme mentions, it requires a free hand or an archetype override.

Aight bet. I got something for you. Drop the archery feats and get quick draw and quick stow to juggle in and out between ranged and melee, when necessary, you won't be as accurate, but it makes the build functional.

@Masakan since the only way to attack with dual weapons is via full-attack which is a full round action this build would never work (see edit above).

Please re-format this answer to avoid signaling edits and present one cohesive response. Anyone interested in the history of how you got here can view that through the normal mechanism, but for most readers it only makes this extremely difficult to read. Moreover, I’d recommend being clearer that spellstrike itself does not require an empty hand—somatic spells do. There are non-somatic spells, plus numerous ways of performing somatic components and then still using both hands for weapon(s).

@niekell I know that's not the point. The point is being able to seamlessly swap between ranged and melee combat when needed, not using both at the same time. That was never the point of this build to begin with.

@Masakan Your question states "hand crossbow in one hand and a sword in the other" which implies dual wielding. Please update the question to be clear that you just want to be able to use either (not both) in any given round.

I still don’t like “Incorrect” as the headline, as it is an inaccurate response to both the title question and one of the two formulations of the question in the body. It is responding to the specific example of frostbite and snowball on a sword and hand crossbow, but I don’t think many readers would assume that to be what it is responding to, given the title and the wording of the body. Also, the claim that “Darkness would only be useful if the Magus had Darkvision and the target didn’t,” is incorrect: darkness cannot be overcome with darkvision. Fancier abilities would be necessary.

@KRyan d20PFSRD Darkness spell states "Creatures with darkvision can see in an area of dim light or darkness without penalty."

@niekell Huh, never knew Pathfinder changed that. Bizarre, I wonder why... it’s not like darkness effects were ever terribly good. Anyway, my bad on not double-checking that.

My reading of the rules also suggests that spellstrike doesn't require a free hand in and of itself even if the casting normally does.
The wording of spellstrike doesn't indicate a need for a free hand:

Spellstrike (Su): At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack. Instead of the free melee touch attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, a magus can make one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell. If successful, this melee attack deals its normal damage as well as the effects of the spell. If the magus makes this attack in concert with spell combat, this melee attack takes all the penalties accrued by spell combat melee attacks. This attack uses the weapon's critical range (20, 19–20, or 18–20 and modified by the keen weapon property or similar effects), but the spell effect only deals ×2 damage on a successful critical hit, while the weapon damage uses its own critical modifier.

Additionally, I think that the Mindblade archetype (from Occult Adventures) is a relevant example. It's plainly designed for having both hands occupied (using psychic casting to avoid somatic components and generating weapons to dual-wield). If spellstrike as-is required a free hand, the Mindblade would need to alter it in order to function properly, which isn't the case. Now, the rules writers are not perfect so it is possible that this is a problem that was missed, but this does line up with a valid interpretation of spellstrike's text.

I'm confused how mindblade would need to adjust Spellstrike since, as you note, psychic spellcasting does not use Somatic components.

If there was something about Spellstrike itself (separate from the rest of the spellcasting process, which I'm assuming would have some other workaround used) that required a free hand, mindblade would need to change that thing in order to work properly. No changes being made then implies that the requirements for a free hand are not part of the spellstrike ability.
